# How to log in to a website Using XML and VBA

Tags: xml, vba, authentication, web-scraping

I am trying to log in to a website using XML and not IE or an HTTP request with VBA. My code does not return any error message, but it does not return any body-element from the logged-in page. Can anyone help me:

```
Sub XMLNavigation()
    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim Acollec As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection, FormCollec  As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    
    Dim Aelement As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLinputUN As MSHTML.IHTMLElement, HTMLinputPW As MSHTML.IHTMLElement, HTMLsubmit As MSHTML.IHTMLElement, LogForm As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
   
    Dim Welcome As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
        
    XMLReq.Open "GET", QlikVwHome, False, UserName, Password
    XMLReq.send
    
    If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & "-" & XMLReq.statusText
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
    Set Welcome = HT
    Set Acollec = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
    
    For Each Aelement In Acollec
        Debug.Print Aelement.getAttribute("class"), Aelement.getAttribute("href")
    Next Aelement
    
    Debug.Print Acollec.Length

End Sub
```

Comment: I get the following return on my debug screen:OK
Null          about:blank
 1

Comment: What is `HT`? It is an http request btw. Have  you inspected the responseText?

Comment: Use a library instead of reinventing the wheel, one SO question at a time. https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web